# Автоматическая генерация кода из UML

Tags: uml, php, кодогенераторы

Вопрос собственно вот в чем. Может, я совсем обленился, конечно, но всё же. Есть среды типа Rational Rose и прочие, где строишь разные UML диаграммы. Вопрос в том, есть ли такие софтины, где из UML или чего другого автоматически генерируется код php?

Comment: Что касается php -- вряд ли. Касательно c++/java -- наверняка. Вопрос один -- нафига? (Это на полном серьёзе, такие инструменты вполне нормально могут продаваться, а вот относительно их полезности в разработке -- не верю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из UML не встречал (да и неискал особо), но вот в различных фрэймворках существует генератор кода для операций `CRUD` с моделями.

Comment: Где конкретно? В ZF есть возможность работы через командную строку. Там можно много чего генерировать. А где ещё?

Comment: Yii, CakePhp)

Comment: Есть уйма код генератротов, н-р в symfony  `https://symfony.com/blog/new-and-improved-generators-for-makerbundle`  так-же есть небольшие  в phpstorm  visualStudio Atom